# "hash" variable in String class

Tags: java, jvm

what is the use of private "hash" variable in java.lang.String class. It is private and calculated/re-calculated every time hashcode method is called.

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used to cache the `hashCode` of the `String`. Because `String` is immutable, its `hashCode` will never change, so attempting to recalculate it after it's already been calculated is pointless.

In the code that you've posted, it's only recalculated when the value of `hash` is `0`, which can either occur if the `hashCode` hasn't been calculated yet **or** if the `hashCode` of the `String` is actually `0`, which is possible!

For example, the `hashCode` of `"aardvark polycyclic bitmap"` is `0`.

This oversight seems to have been corrected in Java 13 with the introduction of a `hashIsZero` field:

```
public int hashCode() {
    // The hash or hashIsZero fields are subject to a benign data race,
    // making it crucial to ensure that any observable result of the
    // calculation in this method stays correct under any possible read of
    // these fields. Necessary restrictions to allow this to be correct
    // without explicit memory fences or similar concurrency primitives is
    // that we can ever only write to one of these two fields for a given
    // String instance, and that the computation is idempotent and derived
    // from immutable state
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && !hashIsZero) {
        h = isLatin1() ? StringLatin1.hashCode(value)
                       : StringUTF16.hashCode(value);
        if (h == 0) {
            hashIsZero = true;
        } else {
            hash = h;
        }
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: That’s not an oversight. It was a trade-off between having to recalculate the value for some strings and adding an additional field for every string instance. But since then, the fields of the string class, as well as the memory layout of JVM implementations, have changed multiple times, further, the relevance of this problem has been reconsidered, as it may open applications to DoS attacks. So nowadays, the additional field has been considered to be no problem, especially as depending on the JVM, some fields may have no impact on the required storage.

Comment: @Holger beautiful comment. this is exactly the case about `code` in `String` class, that had enough gap left to fit that field without impacting the size at all.